# Replace XmlNode with another XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am working in an older piece of code so I do not have the option to use XDocument.

I am trying to replace one XmlNode with another but from some reason XmlDocument.ReplaceChild() complains that: The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

I don't understand why I am getting this error because I am getting reference to the XmlDocument from the element to be replaced.

```
private XmlNode ReplaceWithSpan(XmlNode node)
{
    if (XmlNodeType.Element == node.NodeType)
    {
        XmlDocument ownerDocument = node.OwnerDocument;
        XmlNode spanNode = ownerDocument.CreateElement("span");

        for (int i = 0; i < node.Attributes.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlAttribute attribute = node.Attributes[i];
            AddAttribute(spanNode, attribute.Name, attribute.Value);
        }
        ownerDocument.ReplaceChild(spanNode, node); //this doesn't work
        return spanNode;
    }
    throw new InvalidCastException(string.Format("Could not replace custom edit node of type {0}.", node.NodeType.ToString()));
}
```

Can someone where I've gone wrong?

**Update**

Got it figured out. The problem is that the old node is not a direct child of the owner document. The following change works:

```
  node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(spanNode, node);
  return spanNode;
```

Comment: VS 2010. But the code is older and it uses the old .NET XML api. I would be using XDocument if I could :)